# Android ListView from a many to many db relationship

Tags: android, database, listview, adapter

I have in my db 2 table with a many to many relationship.

TAB_ARTICLES: {_ID, TITLE, BODY, DATE}

TAB_TAG: {_ID, NAME, COLOR, DATE}

TAB_ART_TAG: {_ID, ARTICLE_ID, TAG_ID}

I need to populate a ListView, one row for article and in every row I need to have a TextView for every label linked to that article. Like the following [image](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1gn5aOec3sjQjF4WU53enhjQTQ)

I think 2 solutions.

a. I use a CursorAdapter with a cursor made only on TAB_ARTICLE and than in every row I do a query to join the other 2 tables looking for all tags related at this article. This solution require a lot of db accesses.

b. I realize a temporary table

TABLE_TEMP: {ARTICLE_TITLE, ARTICLE_BODY, ARTICLE_DATE, TAG1_NAME, TAG1_COLOR, TAG2_NAME, TAG2_COLOR, ...}

and I use a query on this table as cursor for custom adapter. This solution use more space and have a limitation on possible displayed tags due to table columns.

Are there other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually, it's a multicriterion thing: time, space, updates, search, etc. So there's no single recipe. It's very probable, however, that multiple queries will bog down scrolling.  Worse, on some devices only. A temporary table may or may not be OK depending on the overall size of your data. And you may want to keep this redundant table in sync with the main one, making simultaneous updates to both.

One of the simplest trade-offs could be adding a redundant TEXT/CLOB column with the tag data (XML, JSON, other markup/separated format) to TAB_ARTICLES and keeping it in sync with your detail data. By the way, you will really need the M:M schema only if your queries substantiate that. Otherwise, the single table would suffice.

Again, I'd list and evaluate all the criteria first and decide what dimensions really need to be scalable and simplify the rest.

Comment: ok, I try to add to the table TAB_ARTICLES a column TAGS where I store all tags data with a format like "idtag1.nametag1.colortag1;idtag2.nametag2.colortag2" creating a class with the job to update and sybc the column